How can I create a new tensor with shape ( k, x.shape), where x is another tensor?
Having tensor x, I want to create a tensor y of the shape (k, x.shape). However, y = torch.empty((k, x.shape)) does not work, since (k, x.shape) is a tuple of type (int, torch.Size). Is there no possibility of achieving this?
Naturally, I could use:
y = torch.empty((k, x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3]))

But this requires knowing the number of dimensions in x...

you can use *tensor.shape to expand the values as parameters
tensor1 = torch.Tensor(x,y)
tensor2 = torch.Tensor(k, *tensor1.shape)


Note that you can unwrap other collections with *, e.g. plain lists torch.Tensor(k, *[1,2,3])
